# og:image NOT WORKING on facebook debugger or on live site

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been working at this for three days...I am trying to have a url shared to facebook, along with a description, and image. Using the facebook debugger tool, under "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties:" all of the information shows up correctly..except it shows the image twice. Below that, where it previews what the facebook post will look like, there is only my site's url and name...no picture or description. Below is my og-tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://thetopanswer.com/images/squareicon.jpg" />
            <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
            <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
            <meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />       
            <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.thetopanswer.com" />
            <meta property="og:title"              content="The Top Answer: a Q&A service, tailored for today." />
            <meta property="og:description"        content="The Top Answer is a question and answer community committed to finding the top answer to every question." />
```

Here is the sharer.php code I am using:

```
  window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + "" + fullHREF,"","height=550,width=525,left=100,top=100,menubar=0");
```

This is an absolute nightmare...people seem to be having similar problems, but I also see shared url's on facebook with images, so this must be possible. I gratefully welcome any/all approaches, techniques, or tips that can help me solve this issue. I have not signed up for an appID on facebook, but I am just trying to share a url, with my company image, and I don't think I need this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the URL to the page?

Comment: The shared url is created dynamically to share an individual question on my Q&A site. The url being passed to fullHREF is: www.thetopanswer.com/index.php?qa=1&qa_1=question-answer-website

Comment: I've added the og:url tag...although this isn't the source of the problem..the facebook debugger is no longer asking me to include this. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: It seems other people have the issue of facebook using a cached image instead of the specified or new image...but my problem, is that the image won't even show up! or the description for that matter.

Comment: og:url is set to https://www.thetopanswer.com which means that Facebook will go and fetch tags from that URL

Comment: Right, but it is not fetching the image tag. Or..the facebook debugger IS fetching it, but not displaying it. Same as the description.

Comment: if you can view download attempts you'll be able to see if its even making a request for the image - this will help determine if it's a caching or syntax issue.